# how to convert 1e+11 into number?

Tags: exponential-function

What will be 1e+11 in number? I know e2 means `* 10^2` but i am confused with this above question. What will its value be?

I know how to use exponential function when required in computer calculator but how does it work? I am still studying and our textbooks are not so detailed which gives us the idea how it works. I am using the function but still anyone can explain me in detail about how  to convert 1e+11 into number?

Comment: Strictly speaking, 1e+11 is a number; what you want is to write the same number in a more familiar notation (which dleggas's answer shows you how to do).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea.

$$1\text{ e+11}=1 \times 10^{+11}$$

You should know that $10$ raised to any positive integer is a $1$ with that many $0$s behind it. So

$$10^{+11}=100000000000$$

Comment: thank you for your reply. i might be able to accept your answer after 11mins(from now) as shown in SO msg. But Unfortunately i am busy right now so could not be back here after 11 mins.  Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: dot sometimes confuse as fraction part, better to use multiplication symbol

Answer (score 10):

It is just a short notation to make good use of limited display and storage space.

The used string in base 10 representation, called exponential or [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), and the encoded rational number are related by
$$
(\underbrace{\pm d.ddd\cdots d}_{\mbox{mantissa }m} \,\,\, \mbox{E}\underbrace{\pm dd\cdots d}_{\mbox{exponent }k})_{10} =
m \cdot 10^k
$$

with digits $d \in \{ 0, \ldots, 9 \}$, exponential symbol "E" or "e", rational $|m| < 10$ and integer $k$.

The exponent is not to be confused with the exponential function 
$e^x$.

Also for some problems the "order of magnitude" (i.e. $10^k$) is good enough and the knowledge of all digits not necessary.

In your example the string "1e+11" means the number 
$1 \cdot 10^{+11} = 10^{11} = 1\underbrace{00000000000}_{11 \, "0" \mbox{symbols}}$

Note that the resulting number is given by a string as well, just a usually more familiar one, the [base 10 positional system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) representation learned in school.

Another example: "0.27e-15" means the number
$0.27 \cdot 10^{-15} = 0.\underbrace{000000000000000}_{15 \, "0" \mbox{symbols}}25$